# Index.html of VPS not working, redirecting to virtual host domain

Tags: nginx

When I type the domain name I linked to my server IP, one of the virtual host websites I have on the server comes up, rather than the index.html file I have as default on the server. Why is this so? I am using Nginx, these are my configuration files:

default
http://pastebin.com/ByQDCAsb

the domain that gets served (replaced domain with mysite.com)
http://pastebin.com/CYJXgkWm

Answer (score 0):

To let Nginx process the "default" directive, you may do the following two changes.

- Change `listen   8080;` to `listen   8080 default_server;`
- Change `server_name localhost;` to `server_name _;`

Please let me know, if it works (or not).